# Qml TextField numeric keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, qml, textfield

I am trying to use a `TextField` that receives only numbers in `QML`. I am using the `inputMethodHints` property to make the device keyboard show just numbers. It works fine in Android but when I run it in iOS it shows the full keyboard, with digits, characters and predictive words.

Code below:

```
TextField {
    id: numeroTelefoneTextField

    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.right: parent.right

    width: parent.width * 0.70
    height: parent.height * 0.6

    placeholderText: qsTr("Seu número")

    font.bold: true

    validator: RegExpValidator{regExp: /\d+/}

    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
}
```

I have tried other options to like `inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly | Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText` and just `inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText` but none of this options worked in iOS.

Comment: for between (0-12) ` validator: IntValidator {bottom: 1; top: 12} focus: true`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved that just removing the validators, but I don't know why it worked without the validator.

Code below:

```
TextField {
    id: numeroTelefoneTextField

    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.right: parent.right

    width: parent.width * 0.70
    height: parent.height * 0.6

    placeholderText: qsTr("Seu número")

    font.bold: true

    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
}
```

Comment: For me it does not work even without validator: on Linux it shows me literal characters keyboard initially, and on any key press in text input - starts to show numeric.

Answer (score 4):

Try following:

```
TextField {
    id: numeroTelefoneTextField

    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.right: parent.right

    width: parent.width * 0.70
    height: parent.height * 0.6

    placeholderText: qsTr("Seu número")

    validator: IntValidator {
        bottom: 1
        top: 100
    }

    font.bold: true

    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
}
```